# enable job results in a sp_send_dbmail error

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-agent, senddbmail

On one of our production servers (SQL SERVER 2017 Enterprise)  I get the following error whenever I right click and enable a Job in the SQL Server Agent:

```
Alter failed for Job 'My Job'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
...
At least one of the following parameters must be specified. "@body, @query, @file_attachments, @subject". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3162&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=14624&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: MyServer
Error Number: 14624
Severity: 16
State: 1
Procedure: msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
Line Number: 242

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
```

The Agent user is a sysadmin.  I'm able to send a mail using the procedure and the mail profile found in the agents Alert properties.  I'm not sure what else to check.  Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: This happens on every job?  Can you capture a profiler trace?

Comment: yes it happens for every job.  what would I want turned on in profiler to try and capture this.  I'm not even sure what I'm looking for at this point.

Comment: I found it by tracing it out through the execution plan after running the sp_update_job.  someone (who is soon to get a piece of my mind) put a trigger on the dbo.sysjobs table.  Error is in their trigger code.

Comment: Did they add a trigger or hack the existing `trig_sysjobs_insert_update` trigger?  Both are bad but have different fixes.